# jQuery Plugin - Public method - Data only targeting one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write a plugin that will select multiple elements and then apply some private methods to them (see code below). Then I also want to give the user the ability to trigger the activation of the plugin's methods manually with a .activate() function.

Here is my code :

- MARKUP : https://github.com/simonwalsh/jquery.imagepox/blob/master/demo/index.html
- JS : https://github.com/simonwalsh/jquery.imagepox/blob/master/dist/jquery.imagepox.js

Basically, when I select multiple items and then try to use the manual activation like so :

```
$(".pox-wrapper").imagepox({ // NOTE: selects two elements
    manualActivation: true
});

var manual = $(".pox-wrapper").data('imagepox');

setTimeout(function(){
    manual.activate();
}, 5000);
```

It will only apply the activate() method to the first element in the query...

This is my first jQuery plugin and I've been able to handle everything so far but I'm not sure about this one or even if it is the right way to effectively call a public method. I also tried using a custom event with an event listener in the plugin but it still only applies the methods on the first element in the page.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not your plugin's fault. `data` does not work like that, it doesnt know how to return data from a collection of elements. Because think about it, each element in the collection contains its own data object!

So when you call data on a collection, it returns the data from the first one. The quick solution would be to change the innards of the `setTimeout` into a loop over all the elements in the set and call activate on them.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".pox-wrapper").each(function(){ 
       $(this).data('imagepox').activate();
    })
}, 5000);
```

It seems to me that you want to add functions to collections of jquery objects. This is the usecase of a jquery plugin. You can create a lightweight one like this:

```
$.fn.imagepox.activate = function(){ //do this after you create your plugin!
  return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data('imagepox');
    if(data){
      data.activate();
    }
  });
};
```

now you can call it like  this:

```
$(".pox-wrapper").imagepox.activate()
```

Comment: Besides using .data, do you have any other ideas ? Basically, I'd like the users to be able to trigger when then want to activate the whole plugin.

Comment: sure, let me add one more hacky idea.

Comment: Oh cool! It works! So if I use a specific class or an id for each elements, I can trigger them individually. That what I wanted :) Not sure it's the most elegant solution but it will have to do ! Thanks a whole lot.